# Is there a way to import database connections and settings from DBVis to DataGrip?

Tags: datagrip, dbvisualizer

I've been using DBVis for years, but some of my coworkers prefer DataGrip. I have about 100 database connections set up in DBVis (I'm a QA tester and this is how I check the data in all our test environments). Is there any way to import these into DataGrip so I can try it out without manually setting everything up again? Each of these uses a different username/password so it would be a lot of work to look them all up again.

Also, same question for all my stored scripts in DBVis (which, again, I have a LOT of). Is there a convenient way to import them in DataGrip so they're always available, or would I have to go search for the individual script file each time to load one?

Comment: Unfortunately, importing from other DBMSs is still a  feature that is not supported.
 
If you want, you can submit a new feature request to YouTrack about it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=DBE

In regards to the scripts. You may copy and paste them directly into the Project Directory

Comment: Thanks, good to know. I decided to just set up a few connections manually and test them out, and concluded DataGrip isn't ideal for me anyway, so I'll stick to DBVis.

Comment: If DBVis save connection properties in some readable format you can try to transform it in into DataGrip datasources.xml format via custom script.

Answer (score 0):

@Miguel-Monteiro answered this for me:

Unfortunately, importing from other DBMSs is still a feature that is not supported. If you want, you can submit a new feature request to YouTrack about it: youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=DBE In regards to the scripts. You may copy and paste them directly into the Project Directory